# If $r+\frac{1}{r}$ is an odd integer then $r$ is irrational

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

> Suppose that there is a real number $r$ such that $r+\frac{1}{r}$ is an odd integer.Then $r$ is irrational.

Let $r\in \Bbb Q$ then $r=\dfrac{p}{q}\implies \dfrac{p}{q}+\dfrac{q}{p}=$odd

$\implies \dfrac{p^2+q^2}{pq}$ is odd integer.

Since  $r+\frac{1}{r}$ is an odd integer$\implies pq\mid p^2+q^2$

How to derive a contradiction from here?

Comment: $p$ and $q$ have no common factor (co-primes).

Comment: People answering this question should note that it does not specify that the real numbers or rationals or integers involved are positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have stated that $\frac pq$ is in lowest terms.  $pq|p^2+q^2$ implies that $p$ divides $q$ and that $q$ divides $p$.

Comment: Does this use the oddness of  $r+\frac{1}{r}$  or just that it is not $2$ with $r=1$?

Comment: @Henry It implies $p=q$, hence $r=1$ and $r+1/r=2$, which contradicts oddness.

Comment: @Henry It is not using oddness at all, but divisibility properties of the integers. You should note that $r=-1$ is another possibility. The conclusion is that no odd integers are possible for rational $r$. Neither are most of the even integers.

Answer (score 2):

We may assume $\gcd(p,q)=1$. Then $p|pq$ and $pq|p^2+q^2$ implies $p|p^2+q^2$ and subsequently, since $p|p^2$, $p|q^2$. Since $p|q^2$ and $p|p^2$, we know $p|\gcd(p^2,q^2)=\gcd(p,q)^2=1$. Thus $p=1$. Then we have $\frac{p^2+q^2}{pq}=\frac{1+q^2}{q}$. Since $q|q^2$ and $q|1+q^2$, we arrive at $q|1\rightarrow q=1$. Then $r=\frac{p}{q}=1$, but $1+\frac{1}{1}$ is not an odd integer.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
\frac{{p^{\,2}  + q^{\,2} }}{{pq}} = \frac{{\left( {p + q} \right)^{\,2}  - 2pq}}{{pq}} = \frac{{\left( {p + q} \right)^{\,2} }}{{pq}} - 2
$$

so
$$
\frac{{\left( {p + q} \right)^{\,2} }}{{pq}} = n\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left( {p + q} \right)^{\,2}  - n\,pq = 0
$$
and the parity table tells you that n cannot be odd
$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr} 
   {p\backslash q} & &  {\rm o} & {\rm e}  \\
\hline
   {\rm o} & &  {n\,{\rm even}} & \emptyset   \\
   {\rm e} & &  \emptyset  & {n\,{\rm even}}  \\
\end{array}
$$